# SQL reference another table as foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL server 2012 from Microsoft and creating a table using the primary key of another table as foreign key here but it says there is a syntax error

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]
    (
         STUDENT_ID  int not null Identity,
         SCHOOL_ID INT NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT PKEY PRIMARY KEY (STUDENT_ID),
         CONSTRAINT FKEY FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID)  REFERENCES USER (USER_ID)

     );
```

it gives me and `sql80001 error` please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`USER` is a [reserved keyword in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). Use `[]` to escape the name

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]
(
     STUDENT_ID  int not null Identity,
     SCHOOL_ID INT NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PKEY PRIMARY KEY (STUDENT_ID),
     CONSTRAINT FKEY FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID)  REFERENCES [USER] (USER_ID)
)
```